# Cannot install JAVA SDK on UBUNTU

Tags: unix, java

Note: I followed all the instructions here: http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-download-install-jdk-6/

1. I went to the java.sun website
2. I ran wget on :  Java SE Development Kit 6u16, jdk-6u16-linux-ia64.bin
3. I chmod 755 the file, and I executed it.
4. I scrolled down the "terms and agreements", and typed "yes".

> ```
> Unpacking...
> Checksumming...
> Extracting...
> ./install.sfx.1354: 1: : not found
> ./install.sfx.1354: 1:ELF2@@h©@@!: not found
> ./install.sfx.1354: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
> Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting
> section of the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.
> ```

EDIT: I am running "64 bit" server from rackspace cloud.
uname -p = x86_64

```
**sudo aptitude install sun-java6-jdk** does not work!

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
No candidate version found for sun-java6-jdk
No candidate version found for sun-java6-jdk
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
Writing extended state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
```

Comment: Just to be sure. You are running an Itanium Proccessor (IA64) and an x64 based processor correct?

Comment: I'm running a 64 bit processor, according to rackspace

Comment: `ia64` is Intel Itanium, but `x86-64` is AMD64, which is completely different and far more common, and is referred to as `x64` by Sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your repositories include multiverse in /etc/apt/sources.list, this should enable aptitude to install the jdk.

Answer (score 4):

How about `aptitude install sun-java6-jdk`?

Comment: This worked for me on my Ubuntu Rackspace Cloud server.  You have to enable Multiverse first (I believe) or it won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the Itantium (ia64) binary installer. You should go back to sun's site and make sure you download the x86 installer. The reason you can't install is because it is looking for IA64 specific pieces.

Your download should be named `jdk-6u16-linux-x64.bin` or `jdk-6u16-linux-x64-rpm.bin` The second one is if you have a RedHat based system